# Exclude one subdomain while creating cookie

Tags: javascript

I really don't have much idea about creating cookie. We have cookie set for `example.com`. Is there any way to exclude `abc.example.com` subdomain from creating cookies and create for rest in JavaScript?

It may be some server level configuration in Apache or at code level.

Can someone guide me in this.

Comment: Apache2::Cookie->new($r,
               -name    => 'Z',
               -path    => '/',
               -value   =>123,
               -expires => '+1M',
               -domain  => .example.com,
 )->bake($r);

Comment: I am using above code and I want to exclude abc.example.com from this domain